# command button doesn't run on server side

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-11, commandbutton

I've got a "select" command button that doesn't fire after doing a post back on my webpage. It will do it if I run in Firefox 34.0.5, but not IE11.

```
                             <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select"
                                Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
```